# Sort list of objects in a stream and return the sorted list as a stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, rxdart

I have list of users. I need to sort this user data based on gender. gender = { 0: 'male', 1: 'female', 2: 'others'}.

I want the date to be ordered in such a way that females are listed first, followed by males and then others i.e, {1, 0, 2}.

```
class User {
  String id;
  String name;
  int gender;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.gender,
  })

  factory users.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data, String documentId) {
    if (data == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return User(
      ...
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => <String, dynamic>{
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to sort the data based on the above condition and return a stream again?

The stream I receive from database is below:

```
Stream<List<User>> users =
        database.usersStream();
```

Now, is users object sortable using rxdart or is there any other way?
and how to do that?

Comment: Why don't you retrieve the users list directly sorted from database? You can filter data in request to the database and get only needed entities immediately without create instances for objects than cannot be use.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I have scenario later that I need to sort it out. This sorting is not in acscending or descending order but 1, 0, 2 .

Comment: You can see [issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxdart/issues/362) in rxdart GitHub repository about `sort`. Otherwise, you can implement sort from answers by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62986854/how-can-you-sort-a-stream-by-timestamp-in-reactivex) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500308/how-to-filter-a-list-of-obseravble-in-rxdart) links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the list in your `usersStream` method.

Try the following steps.

### 1. Implement Comparable in your `User` class and override the `compareTo` method.

```
class User implements Comparable<User> {
  String id;
  String name;
  int gender;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.gender,
  });

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "User(id: $id, gender: $gender)";
  }

  @override
  int compareTo(User other) {
    if (gender == 1) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (other.gender == 1) {
      return 1;
    }
    return gender.compareTo(other.gender);
  }
}
```

### 2. Sort the list in `usersStream` using the `compareTo` method.

```
Stream<List<User>> usersStream() async* {

  //This is dummy data for users.
  List<User> users = List.generate(20, (index) {
    Random random = Random();
    int gender = random.nextInt(3);
    return User(id: index.toString(), gender: gender, name: "User $index");
  });

  //Sorting the list.
  users.sort((User a, User b) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
  });

  yield users;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, someone might have done it. compareTo should actually work for sorting in specific order [1, 0, 2] not in general order [0, 1, 2]. Probably then we can use the following code to sort and return the stream.

```
return users.asyncMap((users) {
      checkIns.sort((User a, User b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
      });
      return users;
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand  "should actually work for sorting in specific order [1, 0, 2] not in general order" this @RameshKumar

Comment: It worked thanks @Zeus!

compareTo worked as like you did.
 ```int compareTo(User other) {
    if (gender == 1) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (other.gender == 1) {
      return 1;
    }
    return gender.compareTo(other.gender);
  }```

and 
the following code to return stream of list of sorted users: 
 ```return users.asyncMap((users) { checkIns.sort((User a, User b) { return a.compareTo(b); }); return users; });```